# Java Netbeans Absolute Path

Tags: java, netbeans, helper

I created a text editor and a Save button, i need to create an absolute finder so that if the user does not enter .txt the program will automatically do it so it always saves as txt file. Some help pls?

Code for my save button

```
private void btnSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    JFileChooser chooseFile = new JFileChooser();
    int choosing = chooseFile.showSaveDialog(this);

    if ( choosing == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        try {
            PrintWriter fileSave = new PrintWriter(chooseFile.getSelectedFile());
            //absolute path ends with 

            fileSave.printf(txtArea.getText());
            fileSave.close();
            txtStatus.setText("Saved");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TextEditor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just check `chooseFile.getSelectedFile()` and append ".txt" if required?

Answer (score 1):

```
   import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

     File f= chooseFile.getSelectedFile();
    String filePath=f.getAbsolutePath();
    if(!filePath.endsWith("txt")){
    if(FilenameUtils.indexOfExtension(filePath)==-1){//user has other provided extension
        filePath+=".txt";
    }
    }
```

Comment: @user2964786: I removed the code. You can have the wrapper over JFileChooser dialog and override the getSelectedFile() file API

Comment: Wow, your code assumes that the file extension is exactly three letters long. This was even dangerous when filenames on Windows where usually 8.3 but nowadays this is so many other cases that this check will cause many more problems then that it solves.

Comment: This is much better -> +1